# Is it possible to insert values for multiple columns in a table at a time through my Eclipse project?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

I want to insert values for multiple columns of a table. I am doing an Eclipse Project and I want to feed the data from my project into the database. There are multiple columns in the database and I have values for each of these columns from my Eclipse Project. The JDBC driver and the connections are all done. I just need to figure out how to input these values from the project into the table.

```
public void insert(Double num1, Double num2, Double result) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Calculator",    "root", "");
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO RESULT(ID,VALUE1,VALUE2,RESULT) VALUES (?,?,?,?))");

        stmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
               stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
        if (con != null) {
            try {
               con.close();                    
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to an answer, your are missing the `setXXX` calls to assign values to the `?` in your insert statement, you didn't provide a value for `ID` in your function parameter and you have an extra parenthesis in the prepareStatement.

```
   stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO RESULT(ID,VALUE1,VALUE2,RESULT) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
// stmt.set___(1,___); 
   stmt.setDouble(2,num1);
   stmt.setDouble(3,num2);
   stmt.setDouble(4,result);
```

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1"  -         I did that but now i have this error.

Comment: Found the error, I just misplaced a ")" in the query.Thanks for the help.